# How can I found a "Cannot redeclare class" error

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to implement cache to a symfony app.
I am using the FOSHttpCacheBundle, it works pretty fine I have don't problem with that.
But when I was doing my test I got this error on a page :

`Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event`

Problem is I don't know how can I find the bug...
I got it only in this page.
The only thing I know is can fix this bug by commenting the line

```
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
```

which lead to

```
require_once __DIR__.'/AppKernel.php';

use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\UserContextSubscriber;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\PurgeSubscriber;
use FOS\HttpCacheBundle\SymfonyCache\EventDispatchingHttpCache;

class AppCache extends EventDispatchingHttpCache
{
    public function getDefaultSubscribers()
    {
        $subscribers[] = new PurgeSubscriber(array('purge_client_ips' => 'localhost'));

        return $subscribers;
    }
}
```

So have an idea what do I need to check ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a difficult to say "why" without debugging  but you can try to check if class already registered

```
if(!class_exists('Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event'){
            use FOS\HttpCacheBundle\SymfonyCache\EventDispatchingHttpCache;
}
```